# Access coffeescript function in another file

Tags: coffeescript

I have this main coffeescript code:

```
<script src="libs/coffeeScript.js"> </script>
<script src="maths.coffee"> </script>
<script type="text/coffeescript">

document.write math.cube 2

</script>
```

and this code in the "maths.coffee" file:

```
math ={}
math.cube=(x)->x*x*x
```

Why can I not access the cube function?
I already tried a lot of solutions found on this site, without success.

Answer (score 2):

## The Problem:

When a CoffeeScript file is compiled into JavaScript it is wrapped in an IIFE. So the JS code you end up with looks something like this:

```
(function () {
  var math = {};
  math.cube = function(x) {
    return x * x * x;
  };
})();
```

What this means is that the function is only scoped within that IIFE, which prevents polution of the global namespace.

## The solution:

Because you are including your CoffeeScript inline, you need to explicitly expose any functions you want to use in other files onto a global object, e.g. `window`

```
math = {}
math.cube = (x) -> x * x * x
window.math = math
```

Alternatively, you could compile your CoffeeScript before hand, and pass in the `--bare` option. Then just include the JavaScript file with your page.

Comment: I tried 'window.math = math' but it doesn't work. For objects it works also without 'windows.math = math'. It doesn't work only for functions. I am working in the browser (iPad).